# Maximizing the area of the rectangular part of a running track only

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: A high school is planning to build a new playing field surrounded by a running track. The track coach wants two laps around the track to be 1000 m. The football coach wants the rectangular infield area to be as large as possible.  Can both coaches be satisfied?  Explain.
[image]

My solution:

$2x+\pi d=500$

The area to be maximized is the rectangular part of the field only (not the semicircular ends), so $A=xd$ is the quantity to be maximized. By substitution, $A(x)=-\frac{2}{\pi}x^2+\frac{500}{\pi}x$

And $x=125$ and $d=\frac{250}{\pi}$

So each straight part of the track is 125 m, and each rounded part of the track is also 125 m. And $d$ is approx. 80 m. OK, but what does the question mean by "Can both coaches be satisfied? Explain." What criteria are you supposed to use to decide if the coaches are satisfied?

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is about of find the dimensions in order to that the perimeter be 500 m and the area of the rectangular field be maximum.

Comment: Are they both smiling? More specifically, have their design specifications been met? And the answer is not clear. Certainly area has been maximized **given** that one has to meet the track coach's specifications. But no self-respecting football coach would would want to let the track coach have primary input.

Comment: @AndréNicolas LOL. Humor aside, it's nice to get validation from someone who knows a lot more math than me that there's lack of clarity in the last part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you solved the important part of the problem. The last question is not very mathematical. The track coach will be satisfied because you made two laps around the track to be 1000 m. As for the football coach, you could answer you did the best you could for him (the area is as large as possible), but if he will be satisfied or not depends on how grumpy he is.

Comment: I appreciate the humor in your answer! Yes, you have expressed exactly what I was thinking, but being not too advanced in math I thought I might be missing something. Thank you for your answer.